# Creating a variable with randomized number from an old variable (with a higher population)

Tags: r, dataframe

I am not very good at R, and I have a problem. As I want to do a linear regression between two variables from different datasets, i run into the proble, that one dataset is way bigger than the other. So, in order to bypass that problem, I want to create a smaller variable with an equal population, randomly selected from the greater datasets variable. What is the command for that? And if any specification is needed for that, please let me know! Thank you so much for your help!

Tried to make a liner regression out of two datasets, but as one is bigger than the other, it did not help, and the line (error)

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = lobby_expenditure$expend \~ compustat$lct,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'compustat$lct')
```

appeared

Comment: As a new contributor, please participate and do respond to the inputs from SO and accept / upvote answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example; `y` comes from `d2` and a sample of rows from `d1` are selected for `x`

```
d1=data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
d2=data.frame(y=rnorm(10))

lm(d2$y~d1[sample(1:nrow(d1),nrow(d2)),"x"])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get any sample rows, use `dplyr::sample_n`
Example : dataset :

```
df2 <- read_table('Individual Site
1          A
2          B
3          A
4          C
5          C
6          B
7          A
8          B
9          C')
```

with `sample_n(df2,2)` where 2 is number of samples you want, you can get random rows. The following output may differ in your case since its random.

```
#A tibble: 2 x 2
  Individual Site 
       <dbl> <chr>
1          4 C    
2          5 C
```